# Port binding exception starting activemq

Tags: jvm, activemq-classic

I am trying to start activeMq using the command

```
activemq.bat start
```

However using this command stops active MQ; which looks like the cause is port is not available. Here is the error snippet:

```
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.10.0 (localhost, ID:LT7634-51673-1426517344431-0:1) is starting
ERROR | Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ ([localhost, ID:LT7634-51673-1426517344431-0:1], java.io.IOException: Transport Connector could not
be registered in JMX: Failed to bind to server socket: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 due to:
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind)
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.10.0 (localhost, ID:LT7634-51673-1426517344431-0:1) is shutting down
```

However; I have verified that the port 61616 is actually not being used by any other program. I did this by doing the following in a command prompt:

```
netstat -aon | findstr "61616"
```

I am unable to isolate what could have caused this.
Is there any other way to find issues that might be causing this? I also checked activemq.log; which pretty much shows the same logs as in the console.

Things that I have tried and does not work:
1. Tried restarting the system.

2. tried to find processes that has activemq, amq or apache using netsta -aon command. Found nothing.
3. Tried deleting the kahadb folder under %ACTIVEMQ_HOME%\data folder. The folder gets recreated.

Adding the complete console output

```
D:\DevProgs\Dumps\Apache\Activemq-5.10.0\bin>activemq.bat start
Java Runtime: Oracle Corporation 1.7.0_60 D:\DevProgs\Installed\JAVA\JDKs\jdk1.7.0_60\jre
  Heap sizes: current=1005568k  free=989808k  max=1005568k
    JVM args: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Xms1G -Xmx1G -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.con
fig=D:\DevProgs\Dumps\Apache\Activemq-5.10.0\conf\login.config -Dactivemq.classpath=D:\DevProgs\Dumps\Apache\Activemq-5.10.0\conf;D:\DevProg
s\Dumps\Apache\Activemq-5.10.0/conf;D:\DevProgs\Dumps\Apache\Activemq-5.10.0/conf; -Dactivemq.home=D:\DevProgs\Dumps\Apache\Activemq-5.10.0
-Dactivemq.base=D:\DevProgs\Dumps\Apache\Activemq-5.10.0 -Dactivemq.conf=D:\DevProgs\Dumps\Apache\Activemq-5.10.0\conf -Dactivemq.data=D:\De
vProgs\Dumps\Apache\Activemq-5.10.0\data -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\DevProgs\Dumps\Apache\Activemq-5.10.0\data\tmp
Extensions classpath:
  [D:\DevProgs\Dumps\Apache\Activemq-5.10.0\lib,D:\DevProgs\Dumps\Apache\Activemq-5.10.0\lib\camel,D:\DevProgs\Dumps\Apache\Activemq-5.10.0\
lib\optional,D:\DevProgs\Dumps\Apache\Activemq-5.10.0\lib\web,D:\DevProgs\Dumps\Apache\Activemq-5.10.0\lib\extra]
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: D:\DevProgs\Dumps\Apache\Activemq-5.10.0
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: D:\DevProgs\Dumps\Apache\Activemq-5.10.0
ACTIVEMQ_CONF: D:\DevProgs\Dumps\Apache\Activemq-5.10.0\conf
ACTIVEMQ_DATA: D:\DevProgs\Dumps\Apache\Activemq-5.10.0\data
Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml
 INFO | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@fa0a4ca: startup date [Mon Mar 16 21:43:44 IST 2015]; root of context hier
archy
 INFO | PListStore:[D:\DevProgs\Dumps\Apache\Activemq-5.10.0\data\localhost\tmp_storage] started
 INFO | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[D:\DevProgs\Dumps\Apache\Activemq-5.10.0\data\kahadb]
 INFO | JMX consoles can connect to service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
 INFO | KahaDB is version 5
 INFO | Recovering from the journal ...
 INFO | Recovery replayed 1 operations from the journal in 0.016 seconds.
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.10.0 (localhost, ID:LT7634-52369-1426522426222-0:1) is starting
ERROR | Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ ([localhost, ID:LT7634-52369-1426522426222-0:1], java.io.IOException: Transport Connector could not
be registered in JMX: Failed to bind to server socket: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 due to:
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind)
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.10.0 (localhost, ID:LT7634-52369-1426522426222-0:1) is shutting down
 INFO | Connector openwire stopped
 INFO | Connector amqp stopped
 INFO | Connector stomp stopped
 INFO | Connector mqtt stopped
 INFO | Connector ws stopped
 INFO | PListStore:[D:\DevProgs\Dumps\Apache\Activemq-5.10.0\data\localhost\tmp_storage] stopped
 INFO | Stopping async queue tasks
 INFO | Stopping async topic tasks
 INFO | Stopped KahaDB
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.10.0 (localhost, ID:LT7634-52369-1426522426222-0:1) uptime 0.969 seconds
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.10.0 (localhost, ID:LT7634-52369-1426522426222-0:1) is shutdown
 INFO | Closing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@fa0a4ca: startup date [Mon Mar 16 21:43:44 IST 2015]; root of context hierarc
hy
 WARN | Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.
apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@fa0a4ca: startup date [Mon Mar 16 21:43:44 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)[spring-
context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1057)[spring-context-3.2.8
.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010)[spring-context-3.2.8.R
ELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook.run(SpringContextHook.java:30)[activemq-spring-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.stop(BrokerService.java:809)[activemq-broker-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService.stop(XBeanBrokerService.java:122)[activemq-spring-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:601)[activemq-broker-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService.afterPropertiesSet(XBeanBrokerService.java:73)[activemq-spring-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_60]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_60]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFa
ctory.java:1638)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
.java:1579)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.ja
va:1509)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java
:521)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:4
58)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEAS
E.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)[spring
-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.
jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.ja
r:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628
)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:93
2)[spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)[spring-context-3.2.8.
RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)[xbean-spring-3.16.jar
:3.16]
        at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)[xbean-spring-3.16.jar
:3.16]
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.<init>(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)[activemq-spring-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)[activemq-spring-5.10.0.jar:5.1
0.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:67)[activemq-spring-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71)[activemq-broker-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)[activemq-broker-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:87)[activemq-console-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)[activemq-console-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:150)[activemq-console-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)[activemq-console-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:104)[activemq-console-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_60]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_60]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)[activemq.jar:5.10.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)[activemq.jar:5.10.0]
ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or alr
eady closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already cl
osed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:91)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:150)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:104)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the Ap
plicationContext
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.ja
va:171)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1090)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:487)
        at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)
        at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.<init>(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:67)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:87)
        ... 10 more
ERROR: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the Applic
ationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationCo
ntext
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.ja
va:171)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1090)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:487)
        at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)
        at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.<init>(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:67)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:87)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:150)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:104)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)
D:\DevProgs\Dumps\Apache\Activemq-5.10.0\bin>
```

Comment: Check your process list to see if any previous instance of the process might be lingering in a crashed or hanging state. I had the same with a java process once. Going through my process list and killing the corresponding process freed the port.

Comment: I have tried this already. I am using sysinternals Process explorer and TcpView to look for ports and processes but no luck.

Comment: Try rebooting your machine. If the port is free (which it should be), then it means some process is blocking access to the port. Typically, this will be the same process as the one you're trying to start. Can you try `ps -ef | grep apache` to see if any process related to apache is running?

Comment: @Warkst thanks. The PS command finds nothing. I can restart my machine but am just curious to understands what might be working/not working.

Comment: Try grepping some other terms, like activemq, or amq, or whatever might be the name of the process running apache ActiveMQ. I'm pretty sure it must be a crashed instance still lingering somewhere because I can't imagine any other process binding to 61616.

Comment: @Warkst the problem is worst than I thought. Even a restart doesn't help. Am I supposed to start the activemq with "activemq-admin start" or "activemq start" command?

Comment: "activemq start" is the correct command. You could always probe your own computer using nmap to see what or who is running on port 61616. If you are sure nothing is running, maybe there's a permissions error? Try starting activemq with sudo, make sure the correct folders have the correct permissions, ...

Answer (score 2):

In **conf/activemq.xml** which at install dir. change all `transportConnectors` tags uri value from `0.0.0.0` to `127.0.0.1` works for me[macOS sierra 10.12]. 
Seems that activemq cannot bind to 0.0.0.0 in macos. Not surely know it works on win7.

```
<transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
...
```

to

```
<transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://127.0.0.1:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
...
```

and console:

```
jvm 1    | Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml
jvm 1    |  INFO | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@37e52688: startup date [Tue May 16 15:24:47 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
jvm 1    |  INFO | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[/Users/se_ven/seven/apache-activemq/apache-activemq-5.14.5/bin/macosx/../../data/kahadb]
jvm 1    |  INFO | KahaDB is version 6
jvm 1    |  INFO | PListStore:[/Users/se_ven/seven/apache-activemq/apache-activemq-5.14.5/bin/macosx/../../data/localhost/tmp_storage] started
jvm 1    |  INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.5 (localhost, ID:se_ven.code-52987-1494919488296-0:1) is starting
jvm 1    |  INFO | Listening for connections at: tcp://localhost:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
jvm 1    |  INFO | Connector openwire started
jvm 1    |  INFO | Listening for connections at: amqp://localhost:5672?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
jvm 1    |  INFO | Connector amqp started
jvm 1    |  INFO | Listening for connections at: stomp://localhost:61613?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
jvm 1    |  INFO | Connector stomp started
jvm 1    |  INFO | Listening for connections at: mqtt://localhost:1883?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
jvm 1    |  INFO | Connector mqtt started
jvm 1    |  WARN | ServletContext@o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1088a016{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http methods for path: /
jvm 1    |  INFO | Listening for connections at ws://localhost:61614?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
jvm 1    |  INFO | Connector ws started
jvm 1    |  INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.5 (localhost, ID:se_ven.code-52987-1494919488296-0:1) started
jvm 1    |  INFO | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org
jvm 1    |  INFO | No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
jvm 1    |  INFO | ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/
jvm 1    |  INFO | ActiveMQ Jolokia REST API available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/api/jolokia/
jvm 1    |  INFO | Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
jvm 1    |  INFO | No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
jvm 1    |  INFO | jolokia-agent: Using policy access restrictor classpath:/jolokia-access.xml
```

Comment: I have similar problem and tried this but it does not seem to solve the problem, I have also restarted the device but nothing changed